# Java и Windows -- Вывод состояния в панель задач

Tags: java, windows

В некоторых программах в панель задач выводится заполняющая полоса, показывающая процент выполнения какой-то операции. Можно ли это сделать на Java?

Например, при копировании файлов в проводнике полоса показана над свернутым приложением. По-моему, эта возможность добавлена с Windows 7.

[image]

Comment: https://github.com/nativelibs4java/BridJ/blob/master/src/main/demos/TaskbarListDemo.java